# Passing keystore password as JVM args during weblogic start

Tags: logging, ssl, weblogic, keystore

I have a Java client application deployed on weblogic. This client invokes a webservice using two way SSL call. I am passing identity keystore and password as JVM args during weblogic start :

-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/app/identity.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=keystorepassword

It works all fine. However the password gets logged in the weblogic logs in clear text form which is a security issue. Is there a way around this? How do I prevent the password from being logged. I am using weblogic 10.0 MP1 version.

Answer (score 0):

`System.setProperty()`, before you get the `SSLContext`.

Comment: Okay. So 1) There is no option in weblogic to disable the JVM argument from being logged. 2) How do I know where to place System.setProperty() code. I am using spring-ws client. I do not have code to create SSLContext.

Comment: @user825258 (1) is your conclusion, not mine. I didn't say anything about it. (2) do it before you do anything involving SSL, e.g. when initializing the application.